# NoSuchMethodError when using LocalPubSubHelper to test Google Cloud PubSub

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, gradle, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I am trying to use LocalPubSubHelper to unit test my PubSub code but I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(Lcom/google/protobuf/Message;)Lio/grpc/MethodDescriptor$Marshaller;
```

when I do:

```
PubSub localPubsub = helper.getOptions().getService();
```

In my build.gradle, these are the dependencies I have:

```
force 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub:v1-rev8-1.21.0'
force 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.21.0'
force 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.21.0'
force 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:1.21.0'
force 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:0.6.0'
force 'io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.0.1'
force 'io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.0.1'
force 'io.grpc:grpc-core:1.0.1'
force 'com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-common-protos:0.1.4'
force 'io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.3.Final'
force 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.1'
force 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:1.21.0'
force 'io.grpc:grpc-all:0.13.1'
force 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:0.13.1'
force 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:0.13.1'
```

I am not sure what dependency versions are interfering which are causing this error. Can anyone please help?

Thanks,

Abhishek